# Load a view by clicking in a button CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to load a view by clicking  `<a>` with CodeIgniter.

below is my code:

```
<a class='b2' href='<?echo base_url('application/views/create_account')?>'>CREATE AN ACCOUNT</a>
```

but when I click it, I receive the message :

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

the view name is correct.
How can I load a view by clicking in a link or a button?

Comment: You want to call a controller/method to display the view. You cannot access it directly.

Comment: Yes, i treid that.
doing like $this->load->view('create_account').
But when i did that, the view loads when the screen reloads, not when i click the link or button

Comment: If you have a link that goes to a controller/method something like account/display_create_account and then load the view from that, it will show the page. From what you have stated, it's just a link to bring up another view.In the case you are not telling us the whole story here - you had best tell us.

Comment: yes, i want to show the create_account page when the link or button is pressed, not when the page loads, because I have a page before loading create_account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter is MVC based library. It can not load view directly without using controller.

Try this :-

1> Create A Controller in application/controllers.

class Createaccount extends CI_Controller {

```
  function index() {
    $this->load->view('create_account','');
  }
```

}

2> Create route in application/config/routes.php.

```
$route['create_account'] = "CreateAccount";
```

3> Use below code in html :-

```
href = "< ?php echo base_url().'create_account' ?>".
```

Comment: it makes sense creating a route for it, but still, forbidden ;-;
Shoudn't I call directly the controller, and inside the controller, a function called index to call the view? Like $this->load->controller('CreateAccount');
and inside CreateAccount controller I have the method Index, calling the view, like $this->load->view('create_account'). 
I guess it makes sense, but don't work either

Answer (score 1):

Just pass second parameter to load view method as **true** 
`$this->load->view('create_account', true)`. This true will pass the html data from controller and than you can show that data to your existing page via jQuery or other.

In your controller you have to return view like,

```
echo $this->load->view('create_account', [], true);
```

Comment: it still saying its forbidden :(

Comment: I modified my answer please try that, instead of return view from controller try echo it and pass true as third parameter not second and in second set blank array.

Comment: it works, but the view is loaded when page loads, so it appears above the previous div

Comment: You need to create another method in controller and than with jQuery ajax call that method and than you will get view data under ajax success, put that view data to popup or wherever you want to show.

Comment: I tried using `echo base_url('application/views/create_account')`
But it keep saying it's forbidden.
And if i put just `echo base_url('create_account')` it says it was not found :(

Comment: You don't have to pass application/views/ path to load your view. Just passing a file name will do enough. So remove that path and simply load it with $this->load->view('create_account');

Comment: But if do that, the view is loaded with the page, above the other view, i want to load the create_account view just when I click the button or link. I saw a lot of tutorial to just put `<? echo base_url('create_account');?> `

But it gives me **404 Not Found**.
And if I put the path to the view, I get the message **403 Forbidden**.
I'm actually lost rsrs

Comment: I started another project with the basic CodeIgniter installation, now it's working.
Thanks for trying to help anyway, i appreciate it

Comment: Great, but can you confirm that in new project did you remove the index.php from each routes by changing config.php file `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";` to `$config['index_page'] = "";` ? if yes than your old project need to do the same change and you are good to go.

Comment: That's it! My mistake, I did remove that and didn't pay attention, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

pass to the controller first
In view page:

```
<a href="<?=site_url('controller_name/fun_name')?>">CREATE AN ACCOUNT </a>
```

In controller:

```
public function function_name(){
    $this->load->view('create_account', $data, FALSE);  
}
```

Comment: it keeps saying that it's forbidden (403)